# Does MyFaces 2.2 CDI based View scope work for GET requests too?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Does MyFaces 2.2 CDI based View scope remains active for GET requests too ?

Thank you for sharing your expertise.

Comment: How so "too"? This was never the case in JSF 2.0/2.1, let alone in Mojarra 2.2. This is not how the View scope is initially designed/specified. Why exactly did you think/expect that this is different in specifically MyFaces 2.2? Perhaps you're confusing with the new JSF 2.2 Flow scope?

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. "too" is meant for request type not for JSF implementation. As I am using MyFaces, I was interested in that specifically rather than Mojarra. My query was in the context of the article @ http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#1087. Please refer to the bold content in that article, regarding Get requests with javax.faces.view.ViewScoped, towards the end of the section 'CDI compatible @ViewScoped'

Comment: Did you read the article itself? This is like magic and isn't going to work with view scope. That javadoc was just a silly mistake and is removed in the final version.

Comment: Yes. It goes as... _But as said, this comment was removed, **so most likely** the new CDI view scope will NOT magically work for GET requests as well_   As the article author was used **so most likely** phrase, I had little hope. Thanks very much for clarifying that it was indeed a silly mistake. Not sure if I can close this request my self. Appreciate your helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the java ee javax.faces.view.ViewScoped?, then you can add

```
    <f:metadata>
          <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.property}" required="true"/>
    </f:metadata>
```

in your view, if you need an action add this then

```
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.action}" />
```

Comment: Please correct me if wrong, but I assume it will create a new view scope bean on GET request (on Browser Back / Forward / Refresh)

Comment: If you're using `viewScoped` scope and Java EE 7 shouldn't be problems, the view scoped bean is created the first time a request gets to that page, and persists while the next request are partial (ajax updates), if the user changes the page or click refresh then yes, the bean is re-created [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html)